# WebStorm (IDEA) reports a TypeScript error when passing undefined into an optional prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, optional-parameters

#### The problem

This started happening two days ago and I don't know how or why.

Whenever I have a component with an optional prop, Idea reports a TypeScript error when I try to instantiate it with a potentially undefined value - for example:

```js
const Comp: React.FC<{ optional?: string }> = () => null

const renderComp = (optional?: string) => {
  return <Comp optional={optional} />
  //                     ^ Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string
}
```

[image]

I don't like this behaviour. The project still compiles fine when I run the server via CLI, but they flood my *Problems* IDE tab.

Can this be something akin to my TypeScript/IDE settings?

---

#### Some additional, potentially relevant info

One thing I noticed is that in my lowest IDE GUI ribbon, the version of TypeScript is not displayed! I am very sure that there has used to be a number next to it, for example `TypeScript 4.4.4.`, but now the version is gone.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my WebStorm TS config:

[image]

I also have recently upgraded WebStorm to version `2021.3.2` - I'm not sure if this is when these errors started appearing.

Comment: 2 issues here: Typescript language service is not working for some reason, and the IDE own code analysis reports a false error. The second issue is tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55002, please follow it for updates. As for the first one, I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log to it. Did the service stop working for all your files, or some specific ones only?

Comment: @lena Oh, so the error about types I'm getting is not from TS, but some other WS service?

Comment: yes, exactly. Errors from the IDE own annotator are suppressed when tsserver is enabled. But the language service doesn't work in your project (for unknown reason), that's why you get errors from IDEA code analysis tools

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make a supp ticket later today, or tomorrow!